# Do client SSL certificates need to be renewed?

Tags: ssl, arduino, ssl-certificate

I am working on an embedded device (Arduino) that connects securely to specific domains. To achieve this, certificates (domains), e.g. arduino.cc:443, are uploaded to the device via an updater tool (WiFiNINA certificates updater in Arduino IDE).

I'm wondering whether these certificates will need to be updated in the future? The plan is to ship the devices to customers, so I'm hoping this will not be necessary.
As long as the server side domain/website/api keeps its certificates updated, I assume it will not be necessary to update certificates on the clients?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

All certificates have a limited life time and this is true for client certificates too. Depending on the life time of the certificate and the expected life time of the device this means that the certificate needs to be renewed - assuming that normal certificate validation is done. Of course one might decide to use a different certificate validation on the server, like pinning to a specific public key and ignoring any expiration.